# Where to store installation packages for Chef/Puppet?

Tags: chef-infra, puppet, nexus, artifactory

This is the same question as this one, but I have no right to comment so have to start a new question: [Where to Store Local Software Packages for Chef Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073815/where-to-store-local-software-packages-for-chef-recipe#new-answer)

We are using Jenkins to push the build result into Nexus/Artifactory, and using UrbanCode to do the deployment to the servers in the target environments. The infrastructure guys are using Chef to do their installation such as IIS. Now they are asking me, can they use Nexus/Artifactory to store their installation package.

My concern is these installation exe, msi, etc are very large. Would like to ask your experience.

Thanks
Jirong

Comment: I see not problem with large packages on nexus/artifactory, we have artifacts of java programs up to 200MB here in nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper artifact repository is a great choice for storing Ops-releated binaries, and those tools are specially designed for handling large files. For example, with Artifactory you get deduplication out of the box with checksum-based storage, optimized uploads with checksum-based uploads, ability to connect NAT as a binaries storage or even get an "infinite" storage on S3-compatible FS.

Regarding the file types, although the repositories don't list special support for .exe and .msi files, it works great, cause those files doesn't require any special support. 
Once you can setup your files in Maven layout they will work in Nexus. 
Or you can have setup the files in any way you like and use Artifactory.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>